# A file manager to open a zip file like opening a folder, instead of extract it by using a archive manager

Tags: disk-usage, filemanager, zip

I have a small disk space and I want to save every MB of it.

I need only to read zip files without any editing.

But reading it in a archive manager is unfriendly and lengthy, extracting zip file is to wast space very much.

Mounting clouds to add space have a very low speed.

The only way I thinked is to use a file manager which is able to open a zip file like opening a only-read folder.

Any way else?

Comment: Actually I don't understand what is the issue with Archive Manager, it simply shows you the files of `.zip` no need to extract it just click on the file and read.

Comment: For an overview i use mc.

Comment: Think he is asking if there is any way to read zip files as is, without extracting/expanding them.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168807/mount-zip-file-as-a-read-only-filesystem

Comment: `vim archive.zip`

Answer (score 6):

If you want everything to be opened in one window you can use [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3900) alike file manager tools. If you are familiar with Total Commander, you'll get use to it quickly.

Example:

[image: example]

For GTK

```
sudo apt-get install doublecmd-gtk
```

For QT

```
sudo apt-get install doublecmd-qt
```

Answer (score 4):

The Dolphin file manager works that way(*). But installing it may bring in parts of the KDE desktop or the Qt library, so you may have to sacrifice more disk space...

(*) the Gwenview image viewer will also show you pictures in a ZIP

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try B1 Archiver
https://b1.org/